# Magento 2 move an element for desktop only or mobile only

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

is it possible that move an element for the desktop only or mobile-only using xml or any other solution of it.

Comment: Maybe you can do this via Javascript. or Hide and show using CSS.

Comment: Should be easy in CSS based on the viewport size. Doing it otherwise would seem to require complicated and unreliable browser detection.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by CSS and Javascript both, easy you can use Simple CSS.

```
#content {display: block;} 

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
#content {display: none;}
}
```

Comment: The scenario is that I need the same div content for desktop and mobile just need to change the placement of that div. Also, I don't want to duplicate the code.

Comment: I have updated the css

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in XML. Display the element two times using xml, one for mobile and another one for desktop where you want

Using @sangeeta's answer you can display like

```
.mobile-element {display: none;} 

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
    .desktop-element {display: none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by html and simple jQuery also:

```
<div class="custom" style="display:none;">Your html part </div>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var width = $(window).width();
   if(width < 768){  //for mobile only      
       $('.custom').show();        
   }
});
```

Here window.width function works as below:

If you want to display for Mobile: use window width "< 768".
If you want to display for Tablet/desktop devices: use window width "> 767".